# How to rotate android customview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to implement code to rotate a image placed in customized view. Please help me. I am dumb in creating customized view and also have to rotate it. help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a custom view override onDraw() and call canvas.rotate(..) inside that function.

Comment: honestly, i think it is very rude of you asking us to do your homework/job. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Show us that you at least tried to solve this by yourself. Post you code and a specific question and you will get help.

Comment: Hi Renard,this is the code I had tried on creating customized view

Comment: Show the code you have tried.  Edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a custom view you will draw it manually so you can have a boolean value (or a int angle value) representing the state of your view (either rotated or normal).
Depending on this value, your onDraw method will behave differently (for example, coordinates will be inverted)

Maybe, this will be easier for you : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html
Create your rotate animation with the values you want (using the right constructor) and then apply it to your view using View.startAnimation. It should do what you want